# QuickSand not working

Tags: jquery, quicksand

I've been trying to get quicksand to work but it has been a pain and I haven't gotten anywhere.

I can't even get the simplest example to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/KoenvE/wVA6y/

I've been searching and trying things out all day yesterday but with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

The js code I have right now:

```
//QuickSand
var $itemsHolder = $('ul.portfolioSorter');
var $itemsClone = $itemsHolder.clone(); 
var $filterClass = none;

$('ul.dropDownUL li').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$filterClass = $(this).attr('data-value');

if($filterClass == 'all'){
    var $filters = $itemsClone.find('li');
} else {
    var $filters = $itemsClone.find('li[data-type='+ $filterClass +']');
}

$itemsHolder.quicksand($filters, {
    duration: 1000
});
});
```

Comment: you cannot defined var as none `var $filterClass = none;` set it as `""` and seems like the error is coming from the quicksand js.. `msie is undefined..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i have stated in my comment.. you cannot set variable as none.. set is as empty.

```
 var $filterClass = "";
```

and the plugins is using

```
 if ($.browser.msie || (typeof ($.fn.scale) == 'undefined')) {
```

`$.browser` is removed in jquery 1.9 so using older version of jquery works..

> however it is  recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/wVA6y/6/)

Comment: Thanks!
Is there any way to get this piece of code working with jquery 1.9?
If I load 1.7.2 on my actual site all of my jquery stops working because I probably have something which doesn't work with 1.7.2.

Comment: I've found this fix for the missing $.browser:
https://github.com/awshout/quicksand/commit/7103060e447c7e9b8ab1606420ddec9340ca5ee4

Still no effect.